# How to set two intents in a pending intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications

Is possible to set more than one intent for be launched when, in example, the user clicks an notification.

Let me explain my concrete problem:

I have an app with notifications. Each notification open a different Activity (with different extras too).

Now I want to extract info about the notifications usage. So, every time a notification gets open I'd like to launch a Service with some extras.

I'd like to implement that without modifying the existing activities, since they are not "guilty" of the change.

Ideally the pseudocode could be something like that:

```
Intent originalActivityIntent=...;
Intent notificationsAnalyticsIntent=getRegisterNotificationClick(notificationId,username);
PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.multiple(
                                   context,
                                   originalActivityIntent,
                                   notificationsAnalyticsIntent)
```

Having both intents launched when the notification is clicked.

Writting some kind of service/broadcast receiver could be pretty complex since I would need to handle the different params for each Activity.

Any ideas of how to keep this clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached a pretty clean solution. Not perfect but it works and keeps the code clean, It only requires to create a single adapter activity and its transparent for the rest of your app.

In the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.tests.AnalyticsActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

And the java code:

```
public class AnalyticsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String KEY_INTERNAL_COMPONENT = "com.tests.AnalyticsReceiver.COMPONENT";
    private static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "com.tests.AnalyticsReceiver.NOTIFICATION_TYPE";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "com.tests.AnalyticsReceiver.USERNAME";

    public static Intent getLaunchIntent(
            Context context, Intent intent, long notificationType, String username) {
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTERNAL_COMPONENT, intent.getComponent());
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, AnalyticsActivity.class));
        intent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, notificationType);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME,username);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            long notifType=intent.getLongExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, 0);
            String username=intent.getStringExtra(KEY_USERNAME);
            Log.e("RegisterEvent", "notif=" + notifType + ",username=" + username);
            ComponentName componentName=intent.getParcelableExtra(KEY_INTERNAL_COMPONENT);
            intent.setComponent(componentName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The way we solved it is that every `Activity` in out app extends from some base activity and in each notification we pass an extra in the intent that the base activity handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have non perfect but valid for me solution, check the answer in the thread.

Comment: That's pretty nice solution but might have some performance issue (open one more redundant intent) and maybe some UI issues (might see the "analytics activity screen")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by essentially chaining intents. Have the PendingIntent start your `NotificationsAnalyticsIntent`; and then have `NotificationsAnalyticsIntent` start the activity intent. There are several ways to "tell" the notification intent which activity to start. One way is to pass it as a string.

```
Intent intent = NotificationsAnalyticsIntent.newIntent(applicationContext, SomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0);
...

public class NotificationsAnalyticsIntent extends IntentService {

    private static final String EXTRA_ACTIVITY_TO_START = "extra_activity_to_start";

    public static Intent newIntent(final Context context, final Class activityToStart) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationsAnalyticsIntent.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ACTIVITY_TO_START, activityToStart.getSimpleName());
        return intent;
    }

    public NotificationsAnalyticsIntent() {
        super(NotificationsAnalyticsIntent.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable final Intent intent) {
        // .... do notification stuff
        // TODO

        // .... then start activity
        String activityToStart = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ACTIVITY_TO_START);
        try {
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(activityToStart);
            Method method = aClass.getMethod("newIntent", Context.class);
            Context params = getApplicationContext();
            Intent activityIntent = (Intent) method.invoke(null, (Object) params);
            startActivity(activityIntent);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO 
        }

    }
}
```

Several limitations:

1. activity class has to be fully qualified. make sure  activityToStart.getName() returns `com.example.app.SomeActivity`
2. reflection :barf:
3. can't start `SomeActivity` with it's own intent extras without some extra uglieness